# PowerShell script to combine CSVs and add root directory as an additional column

Tags: powershell, csv, get-childitem, import-csv, foreach-object

I'm trying to write my first PowerShell script and I'm struggling to get my head around the object orientation and piping approach. So I've got a directory structure like this (Google Takeout Nest directories):

```
Path\DeviceID-A\
   - Year\
      - Month\
         - year-month-sensors-a.csv
Path\DeviceID-B\
   - Year\
      - Month\
         - year-month-sensors-b.csv
...
```

I want to aggregate all the CSVs together and I've written a simple script that does this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter *.csv | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName | Import-Csv | Export-Csv merged.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append
```

However, I lose the context of the DeviceID when everything is aggregated together. So I'd like to add an additional column that contains those initial root directories, with something similar to:

```
Import-Csv merged.csv | Select-Object *,@{Name='nest_id';Expression={$nestDeviceID}} | Export-Csv merged-v2.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

So each row in year-month-sensors-a.csv would have an additional column called `nest_id` with the value `DeviceID-A` for any CSV under that root directory.

...but I can't quite reconcile the two scripts on how to programmatically iterate through them, whether I need to use `ForEach-Object` or piping.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: The result would be 1 merged CSV with a new column having their parent directory, you're pretty close, tho, can we assume all CSVs have the same headers? If not it will cause errors.

Comment: Yes -- sorry, I should have made that clear. All CSVs are thankfully exactly the same format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before posting the code, I think it's worth mentioning, this *should work* as long as all CSVs have always the same headers / columns. If this was not the case something like this could happen:

```
@'
Col1,Col2
Val1,Val2
'@ |
ConvertFrom-Csv |
Export-Csv ./test.csv -NoTypeInformation

@'
Col1,NewCol
Val1,NewVal
'@ |
ConvertFrom-Csv |
Export-Csv ./test.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append
```

Doing this would throw the following Exception:

> Cannot append CSV content to the following file: ./test.csv. The appended object does not have a property that corresponds to the following column: Col2. To continue with mismatched properties, add the -Force parameter, and then retry the command.

---

To answer your question, you're quite close however, I don't think this is possible as a one liner and if it was, I would certainly not recommend it (others reading your code will thank you for that).

By one liner I mean, pipping `Get-ChildItem` to `Import-Csv` without using a loop ([`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7.2) or [`foreach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_foreach?view=powershell-7.2)). This is where you lose reference of `DeviceID` folder name.

Points to clarify:

- The code will first store the `$mergedCsv` in memory, appending (`-Append`) to a Csv on each loop iteration when it's not needed will cause a big amount of *unnecessary* Disk I/O, hence, not efficient. It might not be important for you in this case, but is something good to know for your future scripts.
- `$file.Directory.Parent.Parent.Name` should give you the `DeviceID` folders name, please correct if I'm wrong.
- Each loop iteration will be importing each CSV and appending the new `Nest_ID` column which contains the `DeviceID` folder name.

```
$mergedCsv = foreach($file in Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter *.csv)
{
    $nestDeviceID = $file.Directory.Parent.Parent.Name
    $csv = Import-Csv $file.FullName
    $csv | Select-Object *, @{
        Name = 'Nest_ID'
        Expression = { $nestDeviceID }
    }
}

# Inspect the Merged CSV
$mergedCsv | Out-GridView

# Export it
$mergedCsv | Export-Csv merged.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thank you Santiago. It worked perfectly first time -- successfully merged ~100 CSVs into over 210,000 lines of data! It also makes a lot sense, I find this a lot more readable. `Out-GridView` is a neat feature too. Thanks again!

Comment: @JamesM happy to help :) glad it worked on the first attempt hehe